# How to add vue3-openlayers plugin to nuxt

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have the following main.ts file in [Vue3](https://v3.vuejs.org/):

```js
import { createApp } from "vue"
import App from "./App.vue";

//How to do this in nuxt3?
import OpenLayersMap from "vue3-openlayers";
import "vue3-openlayers/dist/vue3-openlayers.css";

const app = createApp(App);

//How to do this in nuxt3?
app.use(OpenLayersMap);

app.mount("#app");
```

How can I add the vue3-openlayers plugin to [nuxt3](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To [auto-install a Vue plugin in Nuxt 3](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins#vue-plugins), create a `.js/.ts` file under `<projectDir>/plugins/` (create the directory if needed) with the following boilerplate:

```js
// plugins/my-plugin.js
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(/* MyPlugin */)
})
```

*Since `vue3-openlayers` depends on `window`, the plugin can only be installed client side, so use the `.client.js` extension.*

To load `vue3-openlayers` client side, the `plugin` file would look like this:

```js
// plugins/vue3-openlayers.client.js
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app'
import OpenLayers from 'vue3-openlayers'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(OpenLayers)
})
```

Create `<projectDir>/components/MyMap.vue` with the following [example content from the `vue3-openlayers` docs](https://vue3openlayers.netlify.app/componentsguide/map/#usage):

```html
// components/MyMap.vue
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const center = ref([40, 40])
const projection = ref('EPSG:4326')
const zoom = ref(8)
const rotation = ref(0)
</script>

<template>
  <ol-map :loadTilesWhileAnimating="true" :loadTilesWhileInteracting="true" style="height:400px">
    <ol-view :center="center" :rotation="rotation" :zoom="zoom"
    :projection="projection" />
    <ol-tile-layer>
        <ol-source-osm />
    </ol-tile-layer>
  </ol-map>
</template>

<style scoped>
@import 'vue3-openlayers/dist/vue3-openlayers.css';
</style>
```

*We only want to render `MyMap` on the client because the plugin is only client-side, so use the [`<ClientOnly>` component](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/components#clientonly-component) as a wrapper:*

```html
// app.vue
<template>
  <ClientOnly>
    <MyMap />
    <template #fallback> Loading map... </template>
  </ClientOnly>
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt3-vue3-openlayers?file=plugins%2Fvue3-openlayers.client.js)