# How to use vue-toastification

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I just migrated my project created in vue 3 to nuxt 3. Previously I used the vue-toastification module but now I don't know how to import it correctly. My code using this module.

```
import { useToast, POSITION } from 'vue-toastification'
const toast = useToast()

export default {
    methods: {
        copy(text) {
            toast.success('Copied!', {
                timeout: 2000,
                position: POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
            })
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(text)
        }
    }
}
```

In Vue I had to do `app.use(Toast)` but Nuxt does not have an index.js file. Adding `modules: ['vue-toastification/nuxt']` in nuxt.config.js does not work because I get an error.

Comment: Hi, does that one help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70193023/8816585

Comment: Does it work, is it fixing your issue?

Comment: @kissu yes its works

Comment: had the same issue and solved it like this: - used a plugin helper as decribed below by @ricardo-de-paula and in the component I imported useToast and wrapped the call to it in a conditional if(process.client)

Answer (score 5):

Answers suggested by kissu and Ricardo de Paula worked for me while I was using development server (npm run dev).

After building and running the project I encountered error 500:

> Named export 'useToast' not found. The requested module 'vue-toastification' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports. CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using: `import pkg from 'vue-toastification';`

To fix this, I registered toast as [plugin helper](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins) (I'm using Nuxt 3.1.1 with Nitro 2.1.1):

Inside **vue-toastificaton.client.js**:

```
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app'
import * as vt from 'vue-toastification'
import '@/assets/css/toast.scss'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vt.default)
  return {
    provide: {
      toast: vt.useToast()
    }
  }
})
```

Then in my **component** script setup:

```
//throws an error after production build
//import { useToast } from 'vue-toastification'
//const toast = useToast()
//toast.success('Yay!!!')

//works after production build
const { $toast } = useNuxtApp()
$toast.success('Yay!!!')
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a personal question?

Comment: this is an answer

Answer (score 4):

I was wanting to do the same thing. I read kissu's answer and did the following:

1 - I created a folder for the puglin - plugins

2 - Inside the plugins folder I created a file called vue-toastificaton.client.js

Inside vue-toastificaton.client.js:

```js
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app'
import Toast from 'vue-toastification'
import 'vue-toastification/dist/index.css' // if needed

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(Toast)
})
```

And I used it that way:

```html
<script setup>
import { useToast } from 'vue-toastification'
const toast = useToast()
const onSubmit = () => {
    // use the toast notification plugin to show a success message
    toast.success('Hello world!')
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Usage to avoid an issue on deployment

Since this is a broad type of question, I'll share my experience with `vue-toastification 2`.

The `vue-toastification 2` does not support SSR so you need to ensure that the plugin only runs on the client side only. Follow @kissu's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74679427/21341655) on this thread.

Now on your `script setup`, the syntax is like this.

```js
<script setup>
import { useToast } from 'vue-toastification'
const toast = useToast()

const showToast = () => {
 toast.success( 'Hello World' )
}
</script>
```

**The problem,**
The syntax above will work during the development but not on deployment. You'll get an error like this.
[image]

Even if you follow the instruction shown on the screenshot, the issue will still persist on deployment. That is I think because the `const toast = useToast()` runs on the server-side.

**The solution**
The workaround solution for this issue is to call the `useToast()` directly. Like this

```js
<script setup>
import { useToast } from 'vue-toastification'

const showToast = () => {
 useToast().success( 'Hello World' )
}
</script>
```

Now, it should work on deployment.
[image]

#### If you are using Pinia

```js
import { useToast } from 'vue-toastification'

export const useItems = defineStore('useItems', {
state: () => {
 return {
   ....
 }
},
actions: {
 method() {
  if (process.client) {
     useToast().success('Hello World')
  }
 }
}
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone still encounters this error upon build you can simply add the vue-toastification into `build: { transpile: ['vue-toastification'] }` on nuxt config. You may check https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/esm#transpiling-libraries with regards to this type of issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be available globally, you can install it as a Nuxt plugin as [explained in the official docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins) or in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70193023/8816585).

[vue-toastification](https://github.com/Maronato/vue-toastification) is probably a client-side only plugin, hence you would probably want to use it as
`/plugins/vue-toastificaton.client.js` like this

```js
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app'
import Toast from "vue-toastification"
import "vue-toastification/dist/index.css" // if needed

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(Toast)
})
```

Then, you should be able to use it in your components with either Composition API or Options API (I think).

Answer (score 0):

1. Install `vue-toastification`;
2. Add this:

```js
build: {
  transpile: ['vue-toastification'],
}
```

to your `nuxt.config.ts` file.

3. Create the plugin `toast.ts`;

```
import * as vt from 'vue-toastification';
import 'vue-toastification/dist/index.css';
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app';
    
export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vt.default);
  return {
    provide: {
      toast: vt.useToast()
    }
  }
})
```