# I am using the vue toastification library for notification but it shows the error of outdated optimize dependency

Tags: vue.js, toast

I want to implement the toasts in nuxt 3 but facing issues compatibility. Previously I wast using @nuxtjs/toast for nuxtjs 2 but now I am migrating it to nuxt 3 but that module is not working so i decided to use another library and find out the "vue toastification" but it throws error of outdated dependency.

Comment: You don't say what error you are getting, but maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74667905/how-to-use-vue-toastification

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Nuxt 3 and use toast with this NPM:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-toastify

Comment: But that package does not support SSR, which is really sad!